# Entity Framework Required Foreign Key = validation error on db.SaveChanges

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have these classes for my Company Entity

```
    public class Company
    {
        public Company()
        {
            this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
            this.Tools = new HashSet<Tool>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual CompanyGroup CompanyGroup { get; set; }
    }

    public class CompanyDto
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
    }
```

in the CompaniesController i've added an additional class with the Id parameter for usage in edit/update methods like this

```
    public class CompanyViewEditModel : CompanyDto {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

The Edit Method looks like that:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(CompanyViewEditModel companyViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var company = db.Companies.Find(companyViewModel.Id);
                company.InjectFrom(companyViewModel);
                db.Entry(company).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(companyViewModel);
        }
```

The InjectFrom Method is from ValueInjecter.

Everything works as expected only the db.SaveChanges call fails, because of an validation exception. With some digging in the exceptionI've found out that he thinks the company is invalid because the field CompanyGroup is required but if i take a debugger look at the company variable even after the InjectFrom call everything seems to be fine. The corresponding company group is there.

Comment: Can you please show the source of `InjectFrom`? That's the likely to be place where things go wrong.

Comment: The source should be available here: http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/76924#837330 but as already said.. i think InjectFrom isn't my problem.. the object looks fine in the debugger..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider changing your model as you shouldn't have to mark the navigational property as required. Instead add a FK like so.

```
public class Company
{
    public Company()
    {
        this.Users = new HashSet<User>();
        this.Tools = new HashSet<Tool>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public int CompanyGroupId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Tool> Tools { get; set; }
    public virtual CompanyGroup CompanyGroup { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If I add that, my database shema doesn't fit anymore because the column was named CompanyGroup_Id is there a fast way to change the mapping without the need of a new migration?

Comment: Try `public int CompanyGroup_Id { get; set; }` which will map to the existing column. As you can see underneath EF is just creating a FK for you, so you might as well do it yourself and get it right.

Comment: That was my first try too but somehow the EF realizes that something changed and throws an exception.. if i try to add a migration it tries to create a column named CompanyGroup_Id1 :(

Comment: As you're using Code First this will happen because the `__migrationhistory` table in your database contains a hash of the model that is created from your code. As the model has changed it needs to update the schema so there would be no way of doing it without a migration.

Comment: I've rereated my DB and all the migrations and it works :) I've named the foreign key CompanyGroup_Id but I would like it much more if I can  name it like your sample code to CompanyGroupId. Does that make a difference for EF or can I simply use that name convention without an _ ?

Comment: It makes no difference at all to EF, but most people use it without the underscore. It was only created with an underscore because you omitted the FK relationship in your primary model.

Comment: thank you very much for your help :) i'll change all my models and add the FK keys :)