# Entity Framework validation error when nullable FK is null

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Info: .Net Framework WPF application, Entity Framework 6

When I try to add an entity to my database table with its nullable foreign key set to null, I get the following validation error from Entity Framework:

> Exception thrown: 'System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException' in EntityFramework.dll
> Entity of type "Item" in state "Added" has the following validation errors:
> Property: "SomeForeignKeyId",
> Error: "Field "SomeForeignKeyID" is required.

I have the foreign key declared without any attributes such as `[Required]` as was the case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13067288/entity-framework-required-foreign-key-validation-error-on-db-savechanges), so that answer doesn't apply to me. Its just a simple FK:

```
 public int? SomeForeignKeyId { get; set; }
```

Now a temporary fix for me was to just disable EF validation

```
 Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
```

which obviously isn't the best solution. So what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself (and rather fast lol)

I had this in my model builder

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<ForeignModel>()
     .HasMany(c => c.Items)
     .WithRequired(i => i.ForeignModel)
     .HasForeignKey(i => i.SomeForeignKeyId)
     .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

The `.WithRequired(i => i.ForeignModel)` obviously declared the column as required so the solution is to change it to `.WithOptional(i => i.ForeignModel)`